# How to Add a New Protocol in Network Simulator 2

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, ns2

I have never added a new protocol to NS2 so can anyone please give a complete step by step Introduction to adding a new protocol in ns2???

Answer (score 0):

Google https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+adding+new+protocol

Example http://elmurod.net/en/index.php/archives/157

And for a specific protocol, you can find the latest "step by step" here

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/search.php

ns2 http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/ns2/

ns2 http://network-simulator-ns-2.7690.n7.nabble.com/ns-users-f3.html

ns2 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-users

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)